# Subquery using multiple IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to fetch all the id's in list 1 and with those id's from list 1, I am trying to fetch all the values in list 2 along with the count based on values in list 2.

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (
    id int, 
    l1 varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES
(1,'sun'),
(2,'shine'),
(3,'moon'),
(4,'light'),
(5,'earth'),
(6,'revolves'),
(7,'flow'),
(8,'fire'),
(9,'fighter'),
(10,'sun'),
(10,'shine'),
(11,'shine'),
(12,'moon'),
(1,'revolves'),
(10,'revolves'),
(2,'air'),
(3,'shine'),
(4,'fire'),
(5,'love'),
(6,'sun'),
(7,'rises');

/*
OPERATION 1
fetch all distinct ID's that has values from List 1
List1
sun
moon
earth

Initial OUTPUT1:
distinct_id list1_value
1           sun
3           moon
5           earth
10          sun
12          moon
6           sun


OPERATION2
fetch all the id, count_of_list2_values, list2_values  
based on the id's that we recieved from OPERATION1

List2
shine
revolves

Expected Output:

id  list1-value count_of_list2_values, list2_values  
1     sun              1                 revolves
3     moon             1                 shine
5     earth            0                 NULL
10    sun              2                 shine,revolves
12    moon             0                 NULL
6     sun              1                 revolves
*/
```

My query: 
Here is what I tried

```
select id, count(l1),l1
from @table1
where id in ('shine','revolves') and id in ('sun','moon','earth')
```

How can I achieve this. 
I know this should be a subquery, having multiple in. How can this be achieved?

SQL fiddle Link:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a85dbf51ca5b5d35e87d968c46300bb
[foo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a85dbf51ca5b5d35e87d968c46300bb)
 [foo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a85dbf51ca5b5d35e87d968c46300bb)

Comment: Your input data (table) makes no sense. There is nothing that actually separates the values to "list 1" and "list 2". You have to partition your data first. Then operate on each "list" or "partition" as it was a separate table or relation.

Comment: But this is how my dataset looks like. I am having trouble about how to give one output as an input to another query and operate the input on a new list

Comment: Your query cannot work in SQL. What your query does is to request from the same value to be AT ONCE both in 'shine' or 'revolves' and in 'sun' etc. The WHERE clause in SQL operates on EACH ROW alone.

Comment: Ok, so do you at least know how is the data partitioned? Is "10, shine" on list 1 or list 2? Do you know how to separate both lists yourself, manually?

Comment: are you using Sql Server 2008 or some later edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this could be done. Here's how I'd do it:

First set up the data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (
    id int, 
    l1 varchar(20)
) ;

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES
(1,'sun'),
(2,'shine'),
(3,'moon'),
(4,'light'),
(5,'earth'),
(6,'revolves'),
(7,'flow'),
(8,'fire'),
(9,'fighter'),
(10,'sun'),
(10,'shine'),
(11,'shine'),
(12,'moon'),
(1,'revolves'),
(10,'revolves'),
(2,'air'),
(3,'shine'),
(4,'fire'),
(5,'love'),
(6,'sun'),
(7,'rises') ;
```

Since this is a known list, set the "target" data up as it's own set. (In SQL, tables are almost invariably better to work with than demented lists. Oops, typo! I meant *delimited* lists.)

```
DECLARE @Targets AS TABLE (
    l2 varchar(20)
) ;

INSERT INTO @Targets VALUES
('sun'),
('moon'),
('earth') ;
```

OPERATION 1 
fetch all distinct ID's that has values from List 1
(sun, moon, earth)

Easy enough with a join:

```
SELECT Id
 from @Table1  t1
  inner join @Targets  tg
   on tg.l2 = t1.l1
```

OPERATION 2
fetch all the id, count_of_list2_values, list2_values
based on the id's that we recieved from OPERATION1

If I'm following the desired logic correctly, then (read the "join" comments first):

```
SELECT
   tt.Id
   --  This next counts how many items in the Operation 1 list are not in the target list
   --  (Spaced out, to make it easier to compare with the next line)
  ,sum(       case when tg2.l2 is null then 1 else 0 end) 
   --  And this concatenates them together in a string (in later editions of SQL Server)
  ,string_agg(case when tg2.l2 is null then tt.l1 else null end, ', ')
 from @Table1 tt
  inner join (--  Operation 1 as a subquery, produce list of the Ids to work with
              select t1.id
               from @Table1  t1
                inner join @Targets  tg
                 on tg.l2 = t1.l1
             ) xx
   on xx.id = tt.id
  --  This is used to identify the target values vs. the non-target values
  left outer join @Targets    tg2
   on tg2.l2 = tt.l1
 --  Aggregate, because that's what we need to do
 group by tt.Id
 --  Order it, because why not?
 order by tt.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
with 
cte as(
  select t1.id, t2.l1
  from table1 t1 left join (
    select * from table1 where l1 in ('shine','revolves')
  ) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
  where t1.l1 in ('sun','moon','earth')
),
cte1 as(
  select 
    c.id, 
    stuff(( select ',' + cte.l1 from cte where id = c.id for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') col
  from cte c
)

select 
  id, 
  count(col) count_of_list2_values, 
  max(col) list2_values  
from cte1
group by id
```

The 1st CTE gives these results:

```
id | l1      
-: | :-------
 1 | revolves
 3 | shine   
 5 | null    
10 | shine   
10 | revolves
12 | null    
 6 | revolves
```

and the 2nd operates on these results to concatenate the common grouped values of `l1`.
Finally I use `group by id` and aggergation on the results of the 2nd CTE.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f5205352753eab194b95412331119fed)
Results:

```
id | count_of_list2_values | list2_values  
-: | --------------------: | :-------------
 1 |                     1 | revolves      
 3 |                     1 | shine         
 5 |                     0 | null          
 6 |                     1 | revolves      
10 |                     2 | shine,revolves
12 |                     0 | null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sql Server 2017 then you can use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and [`outer apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply) operator:

```
select
    l1.id,
    l1.l1,
    l2.cnt as count_of_list2_values,
    l2.l1 as list2_values  
from @Table1 as l1
    outer apply (
        select
            count(*) as cnt,
            string_agg(tt.l1, ',') as l1
        from @Table1 as tt
        where
            tt.l1 in ('shine','revolves') and
            tt.id = l1.id
    ) as l2
where
    l1.l1 in ('sun','moon','earth')
```

[<kbd>db fiddle demo</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d66952f57c250e387141ba4952f1835)

In previous editions, I'm not sure it's possible to aggregate and count in one pass without creation of the special function for this. You can, of course, do it like this with [`xquery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), but it might be a bit of an overkill (I'd not do this in production code at least):

```
select
    l1.id,
    l1.l1,
    l2.data.value('count(l1)', 'int'),
    stuff(l2.data.query('for $i in l1 return concat(",",$i/text()[1])').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
from @Table1 as l1
    outer apply (
        select
            tt.l1
        from @Table1 as tt
        where
            tt.l1 in ('shine','revolves') and
            tt.id = l1.id
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as l2(data)
where
    l1.l1 in ('sun','moon','earth')
```

[<kbd>db fiddle demo</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7144a2a129725a48e7469394d2c408f4)

If you don't mind to do it with double scan / seek of the table then you can either use @forpas answer or do something like this:

```
with cte_list2 as (
    select tt.l1, tt.id
    from @Table1 as tt
    where
        tt.l1 in ('shine','revolves')
)
select
    l1.id,
    l1.l1,
    l22.cnt as count_of_list2_values,
    stuff(l21.data.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') as list2_values
from @Table1 as l1
    outer apply (
        select
            ',' + tt.l1
        from cte_list2 as tt
        where
            tt.id = l1.id
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as l21(data)
    outer apply (
        select count(*) as cnt
        from cte_list2 as tt
        where
            tt.id = l1.id
    ) as l22(cnt)
where
    l1.l1 in ('sun','moon','earth')
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2012! what's the alternative to string_agg